Expand BottomSheetScaffold of material3 in Jetpack Compose to the available sheet content instead of fully expanding
I am currently facing issue with BottomSheetScafold in one of the Android application, where I want it to expand to the sheetContent height instead of fully expanding. I know that I can use sheetPeekHeight to achieve it but than I would have to hardcode the peek height, instead I want it to expand until the sheetContent layout height.
Here is my code:
BottomSheetScaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
            sheetContent = { GetSheetContent() },
            sheetDragHandle = {},
            sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(
                topStart = cornerRadius,
                topEnd = cornerRadius
            ),
            sheetPeekHeight = bottomSheetPeekHeight,
            sheetSwipeEnabled = isSheetSwipeEnabled
        ) {
            // Do nothing
        }

Below is the sheet content, I have added some sample content.
@Composable
fun GetSheetContent() {
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
    ) {
       Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_location),
            contentDescription = null
        )
      Text(
        modifier = Modifier.semantics { heading() },
        text = stringResource(id = titleId)
      )
      Text(
        text = stringResource(id = description)
      )
}
}
}

As we know Android has various screen sizes if I hardcode the sheetPeekHeight the sheet content would be fully visible in some phones and some other phones it might not. I did look into other solutions in stackoverflow, didnt get anything which could solve my issue. Any suggestions?
Used sheetPeekHeight to achieve it but than I would have to hardcode the peek height, instead I want it to expand until the sheetContent layout height.

The sheetContent of the BottomSheetScaffold should by default only be as high as the content in expanded state. You can see that from various demos across the internet.
If that is not happening in your case, then there might be something in your GetContent Composable that causes the BottomSheet to take full screen height. This could for example be a fillMaxHeight or fillMaxSize Modifier.
If the code you posted is your actual code, then please try to specify a fixed height for the Image Composable as follows:
@Composable
fun GetSheetContent() {

    Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().wrapContentHeight()
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_location),
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.semantics { heading() },
            text = stringResource(id = titleId)
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = description)
          )
    }

}

If your code is just sample code, please edit your question and post your actual GetContent Composable, there likely is going to be an issue there.
